# Windows Azure: Consuming Third Party Web Service

Tags: azure

I have searched a lot on this topic but didnt get any satifactory answer.

In Windows Azure how can we consume an external (third party) Web Service from the worker roles? Is it as simple as using a web reference in the solution or is it necessary to use Azure Service Bus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's as simple as calling the webservice using whatever method you need (REST, SOAP, etc.).  For .NET developers using .asmx or WCF SOAP services, just generate the proxy like you normally would.  In this model, there is no difference between what you do onpremises when the cloud is the client.

You would look at using the ServiceBus when you are hosting your own services (as opposed to consuming them), typically behind firewalls onpremises, and you want to give secure access to them or integrate them into cloud scenarios.  There are other scenarios and capabilities of course, but that is a main one.  If you simply want to consume another web service, the ServiceBus has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Thanks dunnry. But one more question from here.. I will use worker role instances to communicate with an external web service which has set ip restrictions to access it. In azure do we get fixed ip address of every every worker roles(assuming I am running 3 instances of the worker role) which I can register with the web service provider ?

Comment: Each deployment gets a single IP address. From the outside world, multiple instances of a role appear as one IP address. Only behind the Windows Azure firewall / load balancer do role instances resolve to independent IP addresses. Also: the IP address assigned will change if you delete and redeploy (you can get past this with publishing to Staging and doing a VIP swap). Also, the assigned IP address isn't guaranteed to stay the same forever. It "could" change - though I don't know all the conditions for causing it to change.

Comment: Thanks for that great answer David. But if you say that IP address is not guarenteed to be fixed then what other approach can I adopt to consume the external webservice (which allows only authorized IP addresses to interact with it) from my worker role?

Comment: @Saurabh did you find an answer for that?

Comment: The answer has not changed much.  As long as you do not delete a deployment and only upgrade, the VIP address will remain the same.  Only that much is now guaranteed (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/07/06/windows-azure-deployments-and-the-virtual-ip-address.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

As long as the 3rd-party web service endpoint is reachable, use it the same way you'd use it from an on-premises server. If you need to connect to a service endpoint behind someone's firewall, then you'd want to consider AppFabric Service Bus.

Just remember that you'll be paying for bandwidth out of the data center (unless the 3rd-party web service is Windows Azure homed, and in the same data center).

Comment: David, I still have one more ques in my mind. Can you plz have a look at the comment I have posted below dunnry's answer? Your views on that will be greatly helpful.